# URLSessionDownloadTask doesn't resume on fail

Tags: swift3, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, resume-download, xcode8

URLSessionDownload Task works well for video download but some Authenticated Vimeo URLs for HQ videos(large data) generates following error with no resume data.

**So how do I resume download ???**

I am getting **error** while downloading video task fails (different logs of error are):

1. localized error: Optional(\"The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error\")
2. error debug description: Optional(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 \"Protocol error\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<100201bb 97650a6d 00000000 00000000>})
3. error unsafelyUnwrapped :Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 \"Protocol error\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<100201bb 97650a6d 00000000 00000000>}"

//Code

```
var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?
var SessionRequest : URLRequest?

let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background")

let url = URL(string: urlString)!
SessionRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
SessionRequest?.httpMethod = "GET"
downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: SessionRequest!)
downloadTask?.resume()

//Delegate called sometimes when resulting into error with no RESUME DATA

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {


        if error != nil {
            debugPrint("Task completed: \(String(describing: task)),localized error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription)) error debug desc: \(String(describing: error.debugDescription)) error unsafelyUnwrapped :\(error.unsafelyUnwrapped)")

        let err = error! as NSError
        let data = (err.userInfo)[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData]
         //Above data is always nil so cannot resume
        }
}
```

Comment: My suspicion is that the server is sending back a response that is malformed in some way, and the NSURL* stack is barfing.  With that said, does the session have a delegate?  Are you setting any headers on the NSURLRequest object?  In your session configuration?

Comment: yes i am setting header as when i log response after fail, response contains header set
This are headers set(I get same error if i don't set this header):
 SessionRequest?.setValue("video/mp4", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                SessionRequest?.setValue("bytes", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Ranges")

Comment: As far as I know, Accept-Ranges is not a valid header in a request.  It is exclusively a server response field.  Remove that header.

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Add a complete set of response headers to your question.

Comment: Now , I am not setting any Header values but still i get same error, while i get redirect count as 1 in metrics delegate , with metrics transaction array having 3 values in which last transaction with all null values resulting in this error, i tried to post whole log here but it is exceeding word count, So how can i give you whole log ?

Comment: Just `curl -I <url>` and post the results as a code listing in your question above (replacing anything that you consider confidential with *****).  It shouldn't be *that* long.

Comment: [1] 7355
[2] 7356
[2]+  Done                    profile_id=119
Raxits-MacBook-Pro:~ rakshit$ HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Varnish
Retry-After: 0
Location: "My url"
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 11:52:12 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1549-HHN
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1497354733.580055,VS0,VE0

Comment: Url works on browser, but it redirects to load video

Comment: Please refer to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/236220#236220

Comment: @RakshitKorat Did you ever find a solution to this? Struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @RakshitKorat did you find a solution?

Comment: @animaonline No, rather did it by using alamofire